# How to replace multi line text in html file with a shell script?

Tags: html, bash, css, shell

I have an html file in which I want to replace a style using a shell script using the function `sed`.
I want to replace:

```
    pre {
      font-size: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
    }
```

with:

```
    pre {
      font-size: 18px;
      /*line-height: inherit;*/
    }
```

I tried the following:

```
    sed -i 's/pre {\n   font-size: inherit;\n   line-height: 
    inherit;\n}/pre {\n font-size: 18px;\n  \/\*line-height: 
    inherit;\*\/\n}/g' /path/file.html
```

which runs without any error but does not replace the text.
Note that I'm including tabs to fine-tune the text pattern.
I'm working on ubuntu 18.

Any suggestion will be very grateful.

Comment: Does your `sed` suport the option `-z`?

Comment: Hi @WalterA, apparently it does not support the -z option

Comment: @WalterA, sorry I'm seeing that the sed -z option is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -Ei '
  /^\s*pre\s*\{\s*$/,/^\s*}\s*$/ {
     /^\s*line-height:\s*inherit\s*;\s*$/ s#^(.*)$#/*&*/#;
  }
' /path/file.html
```

The first pair of patterns establishes a range between which the code block inside the curlies will be executed - from `pre {` to `}`.

Inside the block, the pattern establishes which lines will be edited by the substitution, so that it only comments the `line-height` directives.

When matched, it comments the whole line (preserving the whitespace).

P.S. -
      *don't use -iE, that fails.

      -Ei works. ;)*
PH

Comment: Thanks, this works very well to comment the part  `/ * line-height: inherit; * /`
I am a beginner with patterns in shell, now I need to modify your answer to change the part `font-size: 18px;`

Comment: Read, reread, learn and internalize the [regex pattern matching system](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-regular-expressions). Take time and experimentation to grok [substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) in particular. Then edit the above till it does what you need. When/if you have trouble, post the effort and the result as an addendum to your original post with a new comment, and we'll tune it for you. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use matched pattern referencing in sed like:

```
sed -i 's/line-height: inherit;/\/*&*\//g' /path/file.html
```

- Here, we use `line-height: inherit;` to match the search pattern. You could also extend this as a regex instead
- `&` is used to reference the matched text and we put the `\/*` and `*\/` as the enclosing characters

Comment: Hello @akskap, thank you very much for your answer, I think I should be more explicit with the text pattern because otherwise it replaces other lines that match. I keep trying

Answer (score 0):

Based on @PaulHodges answer this works perfectly:

```
    sed -Ei '/^\s*pre\s*\{\s*$/,/^\s*}\s*$/ {/^\s*font-size:\s*inherit\s*;\s*$/ s#^(.*)$#    
    font-size: 18px;#; /^\s*line-height:\s*inherit\s*;\s*$/ s#^(.*)$#/*&*/#;}' /path/file.html
```

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Good job. :) Maybe accept the solution?
Any more questions?